# Skipping JSON_ARRAYAGG array when one of the value is not available-In Oracle

Tags: sql, json, oracle, json-arrayagg

I am working in JSON_ARRAYAGG in Oracle .I have a scenario that Json array have 2 attributes.
One attribute is hardcode value another one fetches value from outer query .

I want to skip whole Json_array to be skipped when the second attribute returns null value. Though I am giving "absent on null returning blob".but still I cant able to achieve that. Any possibilities to arrest that in Oracle.

My query:

```
'field' VALUE
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT(
            '@type' VALUE 'idtype'
            '@value' VALUE tbl.value absent on null returning blob)absent on null returning blob)
            from (select * from table tbl)
```

Expected output :

```
Null
```

Actual output:

```json
  "field": [
    {
      "@type": "idtype"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Add a `where` condition to the subquery: `where tbl.value is not null`. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Hq620pRj)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out any `NULL` values with a `WHERE` filter and use `ABSENT ON NULL` inside the `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and the outer `JSON_OBJECT` (which you do not show in the question but is implied by the key-value pair):

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
         'field' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                         JSON_OBJECT(
                           '@type'  VALUE 'idtype',
                           '@value' VALUE value
                           RETURNING BLOB
                         )
                         ABSENT ON NULL
                         RETURNING BLOB
                       )
                       ABSENT ON NULL
          RETURNING BLOB
        ) AS json
FROM    table_name
WHERE   value IS NOT NULL
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT CAST(NULL AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| JSON |
| --- |
| {} |

Then if you insert a non-`NULL` row:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (value) VALUES (1);
```

Then the output is:

| JSON |
| --- |
| {"field":[{"@type":"idtype","@value":1}]} |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FMvke4aN)